# Cygwin using wildcard to trim all images

Tags: wildcards, cygwin, conversion

Unortunately, I am forced to use windows. So, I installed `Cygwin` to use some Linux commands.

The following command works fine. It replaces an image with its trimmed version.

```
"C:\Program Files\Cygwin\bin\convert" image1.png -trim image1.png
```

However, how can I run this command on all image file?

```
"C:\Program Files\Cygwin\bin\convert" * -trim ????
```

Comment: Cygwin is Gnu/Linux with Linux replaced with a dll. Therefore it is a variant of the Gnu system, but not Linux. It is however still Unix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You installed cygwin, so you can just use its shell for maximum command support : 
`"C:\Program Files\Cygwin\cygwin.bat`
this will give you a bash shell
Then you can change directoty to go to the images location. Suppose your image location is `"D:\Your Name\Images"`, to go there type `cd "/cygdrive/d/Your Name/Images"`
and then call your command using the bash **for loop** :

```
for file in *
do
convert "$file" -trim "$file"
done
```

Comment: because `*` is done by the shell, not by each and every command. That is why your command did not work. On Microsoft's dos the command line interpreter is more primitive, and each command interprets the `*`.

Comment: Fun thing is, when you're going with the `for` loop, you can do the exact same thing in `cmd`: `for %f in (*) do convert "%f" -trim "%f"`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this more of an expansion/enhancement to [@Slyx's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/223590/44356) answer.

Cygwin has a useful utility `cygpath` to convert Windows path to *nix-style understood within Cygwin's `bash` shell:

```
$ cygpath "D:\Path\To\Images"
/cygdrive/d/Path/To/Images
```

Instead of the explicit `for`-loop suggested, you can also consider using `find` that has better support for filtering filenames and arguably safer support for names with spaces (as you may encounter with Windows):

```
find "$(cygpath "D:\Path\To\Images")"/ -type f -name '*.png' -exec convert '{}' -trim '{}' \;
```

1. Inside the directory `D:\Path\To\Images`,
2. Find files (`-type f`) ending with `png` (`-name '*.png'`),
3. And for each of them, `exec` the `convert` command with `'{}'` as (quoted) placeholders for each resulting file.